# figuring out the x,y, and z rotation of a right triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How would I go about it?

Comment: Your question is too vague...

Comment: It is not clear what the question is, nor what data is available for the solution.  Do you want to bring a right triangle into some standard position? Or find what the angles at the vertices are?  Or what?

Comment: How can I make it less vague?

Comment: I have a triangle made of 3 vertices. I need to know what the angle of the triangle is.

Comment: Triangles generally have three vertices, and three angles.

Comment: Yes, and I need all three angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have the co-ordinates $P_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i), \ \ i=1,2,3$ of the vertices and you want to find the angles of the triangle formed by $P_1, P_2, P_3$?

Let the angle at $P_1$ be $\theta_1$.

If

$\displaystyle \vec{a} = (x_3 -x_1, y_3 - y_1, z_3 - z_1)$ 
$\displaystyle \vec{b} =  (x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1, z_2  -z_1)$

The we have that

$\displaystyle |\vec{a}| |\vec{b} | \cos \theta_1 = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$

Where $|\vec{v}|$ is the length of $\vec{v}$ and $\cdot $ is the dot product.

Similarly, you can find the other angles.

For more information, see here: [Understanding the Dot Product](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/math/dot/index.htm).

Comment: Extra credit-this does not require that the triangle be right.